# automatically selecting databasis and columns and searching data

Tags: metadata, teradata

Is it possible to write a query that automatically selects all database names and column names from dbc.Columns table in Teradata, and searches a particular set of values?

Set of values:

```
WHERE abc in (1,2,3)
```

Selecting dbc.columns:

```
SELECT DatabaseName, TableName FROM dbc.COLUMNS
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%abc%'
```

How can I combine this and make a query that will return only those combinations of DatabaseName and TableName where ColumnName has specific subset of values?

UPDATE:

This query finds all database - column combinations:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH FROM a.DatabaseName) || '.' || TRIM( BOTH FROM a.TableName)
FROM dbc.COLUMNS AS a
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%abc%'
```

is it possible to define some variables or sthg. else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write Dynamic SQL statements like

```
SELECT 
   'SELECT ''' || DatabaseName || '.' || TableName || '.' || ColumnName || ''''
   ' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' || DatabaseName || '.' || TableName ||
   ' WHERE ' || ColumnName || ' IN (1,2,3));' 
FROM dbc.ColumnsVX
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%abc%';
```

Running the resulting queries will return one result set with zero or one row for each table.

To get a single result set you need to write a Stored Procedure with a cursor on the dbc.columnsVX result (adding an INSERT INTO temptable), EXECTE IMMEDIATE each row. Finally return the rows of the temptable.

Unless you're an experienced SQL programmer your DBA will not grant you the right to create SPs.

But why do you actually need this kind of info? Looking for a needle in a haystack?

Comment: Thanks for the answer; and yes, it is kind of needle in a haystack search :) The thing is in "IN" part I have strings, and I am having trouble with escaping ' special character. Can you please help me?

Comment: Additionaly, I would also use TRIM( BOTH FROM ... ) function

Comment: You don't need TRIM when you use dbc.ColumnsV[X] because the names are VARCHAR vs. CHAR in dbc.Columns[X].

Comment: Regarding "special characters" for LIKE there're only two, the wildcards "_" and "%". If you need to search for those as characters you use LIKE '...' ESCAPE '.', the char after the escape char is no longer the wildcard. E.g. LIKE '%\_%\%%' ESCAPE '\' searches for any number of chars followed by an underscore followed by any number of chars followed by an percent sign ollowed by any number of chars

Comment: Special characters for IN could only be single quotes: A single quote in a string must be doubled, e.g.
    ' WHERE ' || ColumnName || ' IN (''1'',''2'',''3''));'